# Xpages ExtLib - dynamic content

Tags: themes, xpages, xpages-extlib

When using dynamic content from extlib:

```
<xe:dynamicContent id="dynamicContent1" defaultFacet="key2" useHash="true" disableTheme="false" themeId="Dc">           
    <xp:this.facets>
        <xc:cc_searchTemplate xp:key="key1" />
        <xc:cc_vseZadeveTemplate xp:key="key2" />
    </xp:this.facets>
</xe:dynamicContent>
```

with theme

```
<control>
    <name>Dc</name>
    <property mode="override">
        <name>style</name>
        <value>color:red</value>
    </property>
</control>
```

Theme is not applied to dynamic content div. Also, why doing partial refresh on dynamic content (switch CC) doesnt load resources from custom control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, this control does not have support for styleClass attribute. This can be found on github -> extlib -> dynamiccontent, dynamiccontrol renderer. Also in xsp config files.

Ive extended control and renderer and added style. Class is hardcoded atm.